# Dúvida com Iframe

Tags: iframe

Gostaria de uma ajuda com algo aparentemente é simples. Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível carregar o conteúdo de um Iframe somente quando ele estiver disponível para visualização no browser? Ou seja, quando o usuário chegar naquele ponto? É que esse Iframe deverá carregar um banner. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim. Abaixo mostro duas formas de fazer.

**Exemplo #1 - Comentado:**

```js
{
  let pageTop,
      pageBottom,
      
      elementTop,
      elementBottom

  let iframe = document.querySelector("iframe")

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

    /* Captura o número de pixel (visível ou não) da "janela" na posição Y */
    pageTop = window.pageYOffset
    
    /* Soma o valor acima com o tamanho da tela visível */
    pageBottom = pageTop + window.innerHeight

    /**
     * Soma o tamanho de um elemento e sua posição relativa ao viewport +
     * número de pixel (visível ou não) da "janela" na posição Y
     */
    elementTop = (iframe.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset)
    
    /* Soma o valora cima com a altura do elemento */
    elementBottom = (elementTop + iframe.height)

    /**
     * Realiza as condições para checar se o scroll "chegou" até o elemento
     * Verifica se o atributo "src" está vazio
     */
    if ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop) && iframe.getAttribute("src") === "") {
      console.log("Carregou");
      
      /**
       * Captura o valor do atributo "data-src" e adiciona em "src"
       * forçando o carregamento
       */
      iframe.setAttribute("src",  iframe.getAttribute("data-src") );
    }

  })
}
```

```css
iframe {
  margin: 1000px 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="" data-src="/"></iframe>
```

---

**Exemplo #2 - Com jQuery:**

Caso você ache o código acima confuso, grande etc. Você pode utilizar a biblioteca *[jQuery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)*. Essa biblioteca funciona de forma semelhante ao *exemplo #1*, porém usa *jQuery* para deixar mais fácil para o desenvolvedor.

```js
/**
 * Informa o elemento que desejamos
 * verificar se está ou não visível
 */
$('iframe').appear();

/**
 * Adiciona o evento "appear" para
 * detectar os elementos que estarão
 * visíveis
 */
$('iframe').on('appear', function() {
  if ( $(this).attr("src") == "" ) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"))
  }
});
```

```css
iframe {
  margin: 1000px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.6/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>

<iframe src="" data-src="/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Grande Valdeir. Você é demais. Muito obrigado. Funcionou 100%. Seu eu pudesse apenas dar uma implementação mais precisa ao código te agradeceria muito. Na verdade, eu gostaria de indicar o final de uma DIV especifica para que o Iframe surgisse. Consegue me ajudar mais um pouco?

Comment: Seria isso https://jsfiddle.net/ocungunw/4/ ?

Comment: Olá Valdeir. Vou fazer uns testes mas aparentemente é isso sim.Muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: @LuizAralanLeite Caso tenha ajudado-o, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido. :)

Comment: Excelente. Funcionou 100%. Obrigado.